# How to run dynamically configured aggregations in ksqldb with different groupBy, aggregations functions and windows?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, ksqldb

I need to run many different aggregation queries on same source of data based on user's configured criteria like group by fields, aggregation functions on different fields and with different time windows.

At a give moment there can be as many as 10s of such configurations running simultaneously.
These would be long running aggregations not some kind of short analytics queries.

I tried following

1. Create input stream on input kafka topic

```
CREATE STREAM my_input_stream 
(some_id VARCHAR, someanother_uuid VARCHAR, field11 VARCHAR, number1 INT, number2 INT)
With (kafka_topic='my_input', value_format='json', partitions=1);
```

2. Create stream partitioned by required group by columns of the configuration1

```
CREATE STREAM my_input_stream_agg_1
  WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='my_input_stream_agg_1', format='json') AS
  SELECT 
    some_id,
    someanother_uuid,
    number1
  FROM my_input_stream
  PARTITION BY some_id, someanother_uuid
  EMIT CHANGES;
```

3. Create Aggregate on partitioned stream according to configuration1

```
CREATE TABLE my_input_stream_agg_1_sink
WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='my_input_stream_agg_1_sink', format='json')
AS SELECT some_id, someanother_uuid, SUM(number1)
FROM my_input_stream_agg_1
WINDOW TUMBLING (SIZE 60 SECONDS)
GROUP BY some_id, someanother_uuid
EMIT FINAL;
```

This kind of approach would work.
But this would create 2 extra kafka topics and one repartitioning operation per user configuration.
Given that I need to run many such aggregations, this might be very expensive as well as slower approach.

What other alternative ways are there to achieve it with ksqldb.
Would I be better off with some lower level tech like kafka streams here ?